# How can I make a generic Sequence Filter wrapper? Filter contains same block for both Set and Array types

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions

I have places where I have both `Set` and `Array` of `MyType`.

In these places, I need to filter down my `Sequences`, and you'll notice that the `filter` block is the same for both `Sequence` types.

Is there any way I can implement a generic `Sequence` extension, where the `filterFor` method will return the correct type (`Set` or `Array`), depending on the receiver?

```
extension Set where Element: MyType {
    func filterFor(valueToMatch:String) -> Set<MyType> {
        return self.filter{
            $0.myProperty.caseInsensitiveCompare(valueToMatch) == .orderedSame
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: MyType {
    func filterFor(valueToMatch:String) -> [MyType] {
        return self.filter{
            $0.myProperty.caseInsensitiveCompare(valueToMatch) == .orderedSame
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. `Set` has two overloads of `filter(_:)`, with these types:

1. `func filter(_ isIncluded: (Self.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Element]`
2. `func filter(_ isIncluded: (Self.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Set<Self.Element>`

The first is the implementation that satisfies the requirements of conformance to `Sequence`. The latter is just a method that `Set` implements, that isn't tied to any protocol.

There is no generic way to reference a variant of `Filter` that returns anything besides `Array<Self.Element>`. There is a Swift Evolution proposal to fix this ([SE-0174 - Change filter to return an associated type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0174-filter-range-replaceable.md)). It has been accepted, but has not been implemented yet.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for digging up the links for me, I'll deal with the two implementations for now then :)